# Log4j AsyncAppender info

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am working on a project and we are having the log level to Debug on in Java Mission Control I am seeing that under Top Blocking Locks I have a class `org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger`. We have set our system to Error level and this class disappeared from the Blocking logs.

I am looking to implement `AsyncAppender` but I am not sure of the buffsize that I should give it. Also what happens if the buffsize is exceeded by the system. Will it just not write the logs or will it crash ? I am using a property file called `log4j.properties` in which I have

```
log4j.appender.CONSOLE_C=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
```

How would I add an `AsyncAppender` and the buffsize?

Comment: I've edited your question to try to make it easier to read. Could you please review what I've done and make sure the question has the same meaning?